# How to use onclicklistener on multiple imageview in a fragment to open another activity

Tags: android

It's only run for one `ImageView` in a `Fragment`, but when I used the same code for more than one `ImageView` there's an error.

My code:

```
/**
 1. A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */

public class MainFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{

ImageView imageview_projectimage1,imageview_projectimage2,imageview_projectimage3;
private View mview1,mview2,mview3;


public MainFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    mview1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    getUiInitiazalization();
    return mview1;
   // mview2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main,container,false);
     // getUiInitiazalization();
     // return mview2;
   // mview3 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    //getUiInitiazalization();
    //return mview3;
}
public void getUiInitiazalization(){
    imageview_projectimage1=(ImageView)mview1.findViewById(R.id.img1);
    imageview_projectimage1.setOnClickListener(this);
   // imageview_projectimage2=(ImageView)mview2.findViewById(R.id.img2);
   // imageview_projectimage2.setOnClickListener(this);
  //  imageview_projectimage3=(ImageView)mview3.findViewById(R.id.img3);
  //  imageview_projectimage3.setOnClickListener(this);
}



@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId())
    {
        case R.id.img1:
            Intent i1 = new Intent(getContext(),Grocery.class);
            startActivity(i1);
            break;
     /*   case R.id.img2:
            Intent i2 = new Intent(getContext(),Handicrft.class);
            startActivity(i2);
            break;
        case R.id.img3:
            Intent i3 = new Intent(getContext(),Electronics.class);
            startActivity(i3);
            break;*/
            default:
                break;
    }

}
}
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: post the error please

Answer (score 0):

```
Define a single return type view in onCreateView();
And use layout to add all your custom inflated views in this layout.


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

LinearLayout containor=(LinearLayout)view.findViewByID(R.id.your_layout_id);

view1=inflater.inflate(R.layout.view1, ,null);
img1=(ImageView)view1.findViewByID(R.id.imag1);
img1.setonClickListener(this);


view2=inflater.inflate(R.layout.view2, null);
img12=(ImageView)view2.findViewByID(R.id.imag1);
img12.setonClickListener(this);
view.addView(view1);
view.addView(view2);

    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the following changes in your code :

```
public void getUiInitiazalization(){
    imageview_projectimage1=(ImageView)mview1.findViewById(R.id.img1);
    imageview_projectimage1.setOnClickListener(this);
    imageview_projectimage2=(ImageView)**mview1**.findViewById(R.id.img2);
    imageview_projectimage2.setOnClickListener(this);
    imageview_projectimage3=(ImageView)**mview1**.findViewById(R.id.img3);
    imageview_projectimage3.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

> Kindly do not make any changes in onCreateView. This is because view should be inflated only once and all the images img1, img2 and img3 lies in the same layout file which is already been inflated. So one inflate statement is sufficient.

Also, uncomment the code for click handling in **onClick** for R.id.img2 and R.id.img3